# Returning user data for forms that have errors in when using ModelForms

Tags: django, django-forms

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from client.models import ClientDetails, ClientAddress, ClientPhone
from snippets.UKPhoneNumberForm import UKPhoneNumberField

class ClientDetailsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ClientDetails

class ClientAddressForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ClientAddress

class ClientPhoneForm(ModelForm):
    number = UKPhoneNumberField()

    class Meta:
        model = ClientPhone
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, redirect
from django.template import RequestContext
from client.forms import ClientDetailsForm, ClientAddressForm, ClientPhoneForm

def new_client_view(request):
    formDetails = ClientDetailsForm(initial={'marital_status':'u'})
    formAddress = ClientAddressForm()
    formHomePhone = ClientPhoneForm(initial={'phone_type':'home'})
    formWorkPhone = ClientPhoneForm(initial={'phone_type':'work'})
    formMobilePhone = ClientPhoneForm(initial={'phone_type':'mobi'})
    return render_to_response('client/new_client.html', {'formDetails': formDetails, 'formAddress': formAddress, 'formHomePhone': formHomePhone, 'formWorkPhone': formWorkPhone, 'formMobilePhone': formMobilePhone}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

new_client.html

```
<form action="." method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    {{ formDetails.as_table }}
                    {{ formAddress.as_table }}
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    {{ formHomePhone.as_table }}
                    {{ formWorkPhone.as_table }}
                    {{ formMobilePhone.as_table }}
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**How should I write `views.py` so that if the user's data raises an error, instead of showing them the form again with the errors in but none of their original data, it shows them the form again with the errors AND their original data?**

Comment: Take a look at the documentation, especially the section "Working with forms / Using forms in a view": http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view

Comment: none of that helps when it comes to ModelForms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MYYN says, look here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view

ModelForms are Forms too and using them is no different.

```
if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
    form = ContactForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
    # now your form contains the values submitted
else:  
    form = ContactForm() # empty form
```

The django forms should always return the errors AND their originally submitted data.

The only way you would get errors and not their data is if you did something like passing an empty dictionary to the form.

Your example would never show any errors as you are never passing it data to validate against. It would always show an empty form.

**Initial is not the place to pass in user submitted data**

```
f = Form(initial={'foo':'bar'})
f.is_valid()
False
f.errors # will not validate or show you errors
```

**Pass in the POST dictionary instead**

```
f = Form({'foo':'bar'})
f.is_valid()
False
f.errors
{'baz': [u'This field is required.']}
```

Comment: So are you saying I can do `formAddress = ClientAddressForm(request.POST)` and django will put the user's form data in the relevant address fields?

Comment: Yes. Check out the docs, they are a great django asset (amazingly clear)

Comment: You right the doc's do show this! My only problem is that I'm using multiple form views inside one form and I didn't know a django form could take a ALL of the POST data (with loads of extra stuff in) and just populate the fields in that form

Comment: Roger that. Your concern is valid: if you have overlapping field names your forms will get confused, which is what the Form `prefix` argument is for.

Comment: just read up on `prefix`'s and can't think when they would be useful (apart from humanizing the names of fields)

Comment: say you have 2 forms that have a `name` field, you need a prefix on one of them or they will conflict

Comment: Actually this is a good example: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.prefix <-- 2 of the same form